# web page in fullScren mode

Tags: angular

How trigger automaticaly web page in fullscreen mode using angular or vanilla js .

i used javascript api for triggering my web app to fullscreen mode ,but this api can't allow to trigger it in fullscreen mode

Comment: I do use [screenfull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenfull) in an Angular app.

Comment: Please share some code that you've already written.

Comment: @snsakib i am using screenfull js library to  trigger the fulScreen mode ,here is my code inside my component    ngOnInit(): void {
    if (screnfull.isEnabled) {
      screnfull.toggle().catch(()=>{})

    }    .

Answer (score 0):

You can use screenfull module [NPM Screenfull Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenfull)

Fullscreen the page

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (screenfull.isEnabled) {
        screenfull.request();
    } else {
        // Ignore or do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: with this solution we have to  click on a bouton . in my case i wan't to trigger automaticaly the fullScreen mode without any user interactions or gestures

Comment: You can put the code in ngOnInit, when the component will load it will automatically go fullscreen